# Is there a way to pass an operator with unknown type in haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism, rank-n-types

I have a function `f op = (op 1 2, op 1.0 2.0)`, which is required to work like this:

```
f (+)
(3, 3.0)
```

But without declaring the type of `f` it works like this:

```
f (+)
(3.0, 3.0)
```

And I'm struggling with declaring the type of `f`. It should take an operator which works with all instances of `Num`. Is it even possible in Haskell?

Comment: Have you tried using `:type` in GHCi to inspect the inferred type of `f`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you forced the operator to work on `Fractional` types by applying it to fractional numbers such as `1.0` and `2.0`. Your code typechecks because `Fractional` is a subtype of `Num` (meaning that each instance of `Fractional` is also an instance of `Num`).

Following experiment in GHCi should make it clear:

```
Prelude> :t 0
0 :: Num p => p
Prelude> :t 0.0
0.0 :: Fractional p => p
Prelude> :t 0 + 0.0  -- Fractional taking advantage!
0 + 0.0 :: Fractional a => a
```

So, if you want to make it work on `Num`s entirely, you just need to get rid of those ".0"s:

```
Prelude> f op = (op 1 2, op 1 2)
Prelude> f (+)
(3, 3)
```

---

## However

If you really need the behavior where the second element of returned tuple is `Fractional` and the first is some more general `Num`, the things get a bit more complicated.

The operator (or actually, function) you pass to `f` has to appear as with **two different types at the same time**. This is normally not possible in plain Haskell, as each type variable gets a fixed assignment with each application – that means that `(+)` needs to decide if it is `Float` or `Int` or what.

This can be, however, changed. The thing you will need to do is to turn on the `Rank2Types` extension by writing `:set -XRank2Types` in GHCi or adding `{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}` at the very top of the `.hs` file. This will allow you to write `f` in a manner in which the type of its argument is more dynamic:

```
f :: (Num t1, Fractional t2)
  => (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> (t1, t2)
f op = (op 1 2, op 1.0 2.0)
```

Now the typechecker won't assign any fixed type to `op`, but instead leave it polymorphic for further specializations. Therefore it may be applied to both `1 :: Int` and `1.0 :: Float` in the same context.

Indeed,

```
Prelude> f (+)
(3,3.0)
```

---

Protip from comments: the type constraint may be relaxed to make the function more general:

```
f :: (Num t1, Num t2)
  => (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> (t1, t2)
f op = (op 1 2, op 1 2)
```

It will work fine in all cases the previous version of `f` would do plus some more where the `snd` of the returned pair could be for instance an `Int`:

```
Prelude> f (+)
(3,3)
Prelude> f (+) :: (Int, Float)
(3,3.0)
```

Comment: You can relax the `Fractional` constraint to `Num`. It'll be tightened by a fractional argument.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to replicate the behavior in the example. But good catch! Will include it

Comment: +1, though I'd add that the original poster may have been looking for a more specialized rank-2 type, like `f :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> (Int, Double)` or similar, with concrete types in the tuple.

Comment: You can add `Ord` to the rank-2 `Num` constraint, or even bump it up to `Real`, while still letting it with with `Integer`, `Int`, `Double`, etc.